# ifconfig not showing interface state and stats(RX/TX)

Tags: server

```
$ifconfig enpXXs0f1
enpXXs0f1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 3c:fd:fe:ca:eb:61  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)

$ ifconfig enpXXs0f1 up
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not permitted

$ sudo ifconfig enpXXs0f1 up

$ ifconfig enpXXs0f1
enpXXs0f1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 3c:fd:fe:ca:eb:61  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)

$
```